# What would be the shape of the Indifference curve with slope 1/xy?

Tags: microeconomics

Let the utility function be: $U(x,y) = \log x +y^2$.
In this case, the MRS is coming out to be $\frac{1}{2xy}$. Thus, how will the shape look like?

Comment: $y^{2}$ is a strange utility function over $y$ because it has increasing marginal utility.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback . But why does that affect the the utility function. We can have utility functions like x^2 + y^2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wolfram Alpha might come with some help. Try entering $\log x+y^2=n$ for different n's (levels of utility). You will get the idea of how the indifference curve looks like.

e.g.
https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=logx%2By%5E2+%3D+1.4